# Preventing XSS (and other attacks) in XSLT generated content

Tags: security, xslt, xss

I have an XSLT stylesheet that processes an XML document to produce HTML.

I've realised that it's possible to manipulate the site in such a way that the user can supply whatever XML they like - unfortunately this is unavoidable, and so I would like to protect myself from XSS (and other attacks) by ensuring that my XSLT stylesheet is capable of safely processing any document.

What do I need to be aware of to achieve this?

**UPDATE:**

I know that by default XSLT escapes output (which can be disabled by using the `disable-output-escaping` attribute) - is this enough to prevent someone from being able to inject malicious HTML elements and attributes?

Comment: Could you explain why you allow users to supply custom xml documents? Could you force validation using a schema to avoid any problems?

Comment: @Simon The XML document is a SQL query execution plan - they aren't allowed to supply it but its simple enough to construct a query (its for the [data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/)) that contains an xml document that is treated as an execution plan - I can't think of way to prevent this from happening.  There is already a [schema](http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan/), but I'm unsure as to how validating against this schema will help prevent attacks?

Comment: This is *not* an XSLT question -- retagged.

Comment: @Dimitre I need my XSLT to safely process an input document, and so I'm pretty sure that any changes are going to have to be made in my XSLT.  If you know of an alternative then let me know :-)

Comment: @Kragen: You can substitute "XSLT" with the name of any other programming language and still the question would be the same -- therefore, this question is not XSLT - specific at all.

Comment: @Dimitre The question is **entirely** XSLT specific - XSLT has its own set of potential pitfalls including default templates, a limited function set and the fact that most of the time XSLT automatically escapes output anyway (meaning that I might not need to do anything - I'm not sure).  There are loads of resources on preventing XSS attacks, but very little specifically on XSLT produced content - I'm not an expert and so I'd like to make sure I don't introduce a vulnerability.  To put it simply - **if someone posts an answer which is not XSLT specific, its not answering the question**

Comment: @Kragen: I *am* an expert in XSLT and I really don't see anything "XSLT" in your question. Don't wonder why there would most likely be no XSLT-specific answers. An XSLT problem definition must include: 1. The source XML document(s). 2.The wanted result. 3. The wanted properties/rules for the transformation. It may also include a complete reproducible example of transformation that produces not the expected results and then the question is what is wrong (explanation) with that transformation. Please, if you are convinced that this is an XSLT question, define your problem along these lines.

Comment: @dim in cases of edit conflicts we recommend deferring to the question owner unless there is active harm to the community which I do not see here.

Comment: @Kragen: Your XSLT code is full of security holes and you'll never discover all of them. Do have a sound sleep. :) I still don't get it why you think XSLT should be different in this respect from any other programming language?

Comment: @Jeff-Atwood: I agree that there is not *active* harm in the question -- it all depends on how you regard the poluting of a tag with non-specific questions.

Comment: @Kragen: the source XML can cause the XML parser to crash -- so, don't worry so much about your XSLT code -- an attacker probably would focus on the XML parser, not on the XSLT code. Processing *any* xml document is like processing *any* data -- dangerous.

Comment: @Kragen: This is a matter of validation. Enforce your XML input as well as your XSLT stylesheet with validation mechanism as [XML Schemas](http://www.w3.org/XML/Schema). Proper input would result in proper output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are processing XML data from an untrusted source and displaying the result on your website, always remember that it is not to be trusted.

- You should never use xsl:copy or xsl:copy-of. If you copy nodes other than text directly, XSS attacks will be possible.
- You should not use complicated or recursive rules. Specially crafted input can create a DoS by delaying the XSLT processing or making the processor crash.
- Also, like you mentioned, do not disable output escaping.

If you are passing the result of the transformation to an SQL server, you should not put any of the provided data in your SQL query.

For example, this is BAD:

```
<xsl:if test="@order">ORDER BY <xsl:value-of select="@order"/></xsl:test>
```

This is GOOD:

```
<xsl:if test="@order">ORDER BY
    <xsl:chose><xsl:when test="@order = 'foo'">foo</xsl:when> [...] </xsl:chose>
</xsl:test>
```

If you really need to pass data to your query, use bind variables.

Comment: Also check your XML input against a schema for errors.  If you don't get bad data into the system you're less likely to have to deal with bad data coming out.

Comment: @Yzmir Ramirez is right. You should **first** validate the input source, and you could even validate the input source with XSLT 2.0 stylesheets. That was the whole reason for validation.